# Declare one object to be of multiple classes, depending on a condition

Tags: c++

This question is based on [Create objects in conditional c++ statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9346477/create-objects-in-conditional-c-statements).

However, in my case I need to declare one object from a choice of multiple classes which will then be passed as argument to a function. Hence, the object has to be declared with a pre-defined name (**obj** in this case).

```
Class1 obj;
Class2 obj;

if (...) {
  obj = Class1(); }
if (...) {
  obj = Class1(a, b); }
else
  obj = Class2();

// Do something on declared object
DoSomething(obj.variable_);
```

Currently the above will not work because of conflicting declaration of `obj`. How should I go about doing this?

Comment: What is the releation between `Class1` and `Class2`? inherit?

Comment: Can `Class1` and `Class2` inherit from a common base class? Or could you provide overloads of `DoSomething` for both `Class1` and `Class2`?

Comment: Class1 and Class2 can inherit from a common base class. I can provide overload of DoSomething

Answer (score 4):

You might not need `std::variant`, if your object doesn't have to be "polymorphic" at run-time. Refactor your code to:

```
if (...) {
  DoSomething(Class1());
if (...) {
  DoSomething(Class1(a, b));
else
  DoSomething(Class2());
```

And make `DoSomething` a template or overload set:

```
void DoSomething(const Class1&) { }
void DoSomething(const Class2&) { }
```

Comment: Very good. On top of this if `DoSomething` overloads are co-routines even better.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant).

```
std::variant<Class1, Class2> var;

if (...) {
  var = Class1(); }
if (...) {
  var = Class1(a, b); }
else
  var = Class2();


std::visit([](auto&& obj) { DoSomething(obj.variable_); }, var);
```

The variant can hold one of the alternatives at a time, which is what you need. And `std::visit` will let you apply code generically to either alternative, so long as the generic lambda can be applied to it.

Answer (score 0):

> The OP said: "Class1 and Class2 can inherit from a common base class. I can provide overload of DoSomething"

Inheritance is OK. But only if it is in a form of "subtyping". Let's assume everyone is aware of that. Canonical example.

[image]

In this case OP's question and code is actually internals of a factory method. One solution might be:

```
 Interface::ptr make ( Interface::subtype which)  
 {
   if ( which == Interface::subtype::one ) 
       return std::make_unique<Class1>();
   return std::make_unique<Class2>();            
 }
```

And the usage is simple:

```
Interface::ptr one = make( Interface::subtype::one  ) ;
Interface::ptr two = make( Interface::subtype::two  ) ;

one->do_something() ;
two->do_something() ;
```

Jut one variant of the common concept. [Working code is here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/k62XyBJLndmYDFWw).

**Option with no polymorphism required**

Is allways a good option. We do not need inheritance. We just need intances that do understand the message `do_something()`.

```cpp
    // no inheritance required
    template<typename T>
      void do_something( T the_t_ ) { the_t_.do_something(); }
```

Ditto

```cpp
    if ( ... ) {
       do_something(Class1{}) ;
    } 
      else if ( ... ) {
      do_something(Class1(a,b)) ;
    } else {
      do_something(Class2());
    }
```

In that case Class1 and Class2 do not need a common base type.

ps: Vittorio's solution is very good. It can be also applied when Class1 and Class2 are completely unrelated.

An interesting variant of that variant could be:

```cpp
if (...) {
  Class1();
if (...) {
  Class1(a, b);
else
  Class2();
```

No function overloads `DoSomething()` but type instances that "do something". Might be the most feasible design but only for some app's.

Answer (score 0):

Solution using simple polymorphism,

```
ClassBase () {
}

Class1 : ClassBase (){
}

Class2 : ClassBase (){
}
```

Then you can use like,

```
ClassBase obj;

if (...) {
  obj = Class1(); }
if (...) {
  obj = Class1(a, b); }
else
  obj = Class2();

// Do something on declared object
DoSomething(obj.variable_);
```