# Extend object lifetime/scope from a `if constexpr` branch

Tags: c++, scope, c++17, constexpr, if-constexpr

Say we have the following code

```cpp
struct MyClass
{
    MyClass() = delete;  // or MyClass() { }
    MyClass(int) { }
    void func() { }
};

int main()
{
    if constexpr (std::is_default_constructible_v<MyClass>) {
        MyClass myObj;
    } else {
        MyClass myObj(10);
    }

    myObj.func();  // Error
}
```

Here I am using `if constexpr` to determine whether the class is default-constructible (or not), and then create an object accordingly. In a way, I *naively* thought this would simplify the different branches down to just the one that's true, i.e.

```cpp
    if constexpr (true) {
        /* instruction branch 1 */
    } else if constexpr (false) {
        /* instruction branch 2 */
    }
```

simply becomes

```cpp
    /* instruction branch 1 */
```

But in reality, it is probably more like this

```cpp
    {
        /* instruction branch 1 */
    }
```

But then the question becomes (going to back to the the very first example), how can I can I keep `myObj` in scope outside the `{ ... }`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create objects in conditional c++ statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9346477/create-objects-in-conditional-c-statements)

Comment: Note that `std::is_default_constructible_v` doesn't test whether `MyClass myObj;` would compile. It is misleadingly named. It basically tests value initialization, not default initialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your code won't work.  `if constexpr` really needs its condition to be dependent.

I'll fix it.

```
template<class MyClass>
void func() {
  MyClass myObj = []{
    if constexpr (std::is_default_constructible_v<MyClass>) {
      return MyClass{};
    } else {
      return MyClass(10);
    }
  }();
  myObj.func();
}
```

now

```
int main() {
  func<MyClass>();
}
```

solves your problem.

Note that under [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) rules, no copies or moves of `MyClass` occur in the above code.

Comment: I had a feeling lambdas were going to be required. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can't extend the lifetime of an object with automatic storage duration beyond the scope in which it's created.

What you can do is create uninitialized storage outside your `if` block and create an object in that storage within the scope of the `if`.  The easiest way to do that is probably `std::optional`:

```
template <typename T>
void foo() {
    std::optional<T> obj;
    if constexpr (std::is_default_constructible_v<T>) {
        obj.emplace();
    } else {
        obj.emplace(10);
    }

    obj->func();
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d4e9a0741967620c)

This does result in a small amount of overhead though, since `std::optional` has to hold an extra flag to determine if it holds an object or not.  If you want to avoid that overhead you could manage the storage yourself:

```
template <typename T>
void foo() {
    std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(T), alignof(T)> storage;
    T* ptr;
    if constexpr (std::is_default_constructible_v<T>) {
        ptr = new(&storage) T{};
    } else {
        ptr = new(&storage) T{10};
    }
    struct destroy {
        destroy(T* ptr) : ptr_{ptr} {}
        ~destroy() { ptr_->~T(); }
        T* ptr_;
    } destroy{ptr};

    ptr->func();
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/46c57b30edcc965b)

---

Note that in both cases I've moved the functionality to a function template.  For `if constexpr` to discard a branch it must be dependent on a template parameter.  If you try to do this directly in `main` the false branch will not be discarded and you will get an error complaining about a missing default constructor.